# How to encode mjpeg with max bitrate/s using gstreamer

Tags: encoding, gstreamer, mjpeg

I am using gstreamer 1.16.2 on windows10, and having trouble making a pipeline to encode a mjpeg video from an image sequence. It makes a washed-out movie. The content has a black background, so it's really visible that the blacks turn into dark gray. Could someone help on that?

input = png image sequence
output expected = .mov 30fps mjpeg with best possible quality achievable, without exceeding a bitrate of 120mbps (960mbit/s)

This is what I got so far

```
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="png_image_sequence_%05d.png" index=0 caps="image/png,framerate=30/1" ! pngdec ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=Y444 ! avenc_mjpeg bitrate=120000000 ! qtmux ! filesink location=output_mjpeg_video.mov
```

Comment: Just for reference, the command below works fine in ffmpeg, and colors are correct. And before someone asks (why not use ffmpeg then), I have to test the pipeline with gstreamer, because I was asked by the embedded engineer, due to some possible hardware decoding incompatibility with the content created with ffmpeg.
 
    ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i "png_image_sequence_%05d.png" -c:v mjpeg -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vf framerate=30 -b:v 120000k output_mjpeg_video.mov

Comment: If black becomes gray it is probably not related to encoding bit rate. This sounds more like a misunderstanding of the video signal - is it interpreted as full range or video range. Could be an issue on encoding side or playback side. You will have to track that down.

Comment: Yeah, I am struggling to track that issue.
it's not the playback, because the result from ffmpeg plays with correct color on my machine. 
I tested with I420, Y42B, and also tested adding chroma-mode (full/none) and gamma-mode (remap/none) properties to the videoconvert, but it all didn't make any noticeable difference in the output.

Comment: I probably narrowed it down to the encoder. I did a test with avenc_mpeg4, using the same source and mux, and the colors were fine. Still don't know how to fix it, though https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/libav/avenc_mjpeg.html

Comment: The color space to Y444 may be it? So you go from RGB to Y444 to RGB again (jpeg transfers back to RGB I believe or does it encode in Y444?)?

Comment: It encodes in Y444 (or at least it should!). That's what the hardware decoder expects as well.

Comment: Ok. but compared to MPEG 4 where you are in YUV space you don't need a RGB->YUV transformation. RGB is often considered full range and YUV video range. If it's different or the source claims somethings different here things can go wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. As far as I understand both cases did convert only once from the original RGB values (PNG seq) to YUV values (both mjpeg and mpeg4 according to gstreamer docs work in YUV). When you talk about "range", do you mean the issue shown in this other post? https://community.nxp.com/thread/453796

Comment: Sorry I misread about the `avenc_mpeg4` part (thought it was mpeg4 source). See https://referencehometheater.com/2014/commentary/rgb-full-vs-limited/ for the video range I talk about. It needs to be checked upon in the chain if source video, decoder, csc and encoder respect the difference and carry the info over (may be a bug in the h.264 enc - or mpeg4 may ignore this info as it is an older standard, cant remember..). So if the PNG carries a wrong info this may propagate throughout the pipeline.